# Tailwind CSS: how to use color variables in tailwind.config.js

Tags: tailwind-css

I want to use color variable (default, or extended) to my extended theme like:

```
module.exports = {
    content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                lime: {
                    '100': 'green'
                }
            },
            backgroundColor: {
                skin: {
                    base: 'bg-red-500',
                    secondary: 'lime-100',
                },
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [],
};
```

but this isn't working. How can I have a class `bg-skin-base` equivalent to `bg-red-500` and another class `bg-skin-secondary` that is equivalent to `bg-[green]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a backgroundColor.  Any colors added under extend > colors are available for `text-`, `bg-`, `border-` etc.

Just add skin under colors and you should be good.

[tailwind docs reference](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors)

```
const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors")

extend: {
   colors: {
      lime: {
        '100': 'green'
      },
      skin: {
        base: '#yourhex",
        secondary: '#yourhex",
        third: colors.violet["500"]
      }
   },
}
```

You can't use bg-red-500 like you have in your example for base.  If you are looking to alias a tailwind color you can either use the hex or use tailwind colors by `const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors")` and then you can do `colors.red[500]` or whatever color you want.

Comment: What do you mean by `Just add skin under colors and you should be good.`? Can you provide a code example?

Comment: @abc added to the answer

Comment: I don't want to use my own hex colors though, I want to use the shade of red in say `bg-red-500`. `base: 'var(--red-500)'` is what I want to do, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You have to require tailwind colors and then you can reference any tailwind color you want (skin.third) is the example above.

Comment: You can extend backgroundColor as an option as well. [Docs reference](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color#customizing-your-theme)